# virtuemart one page checkout payment method issue

Tags: ajax, payment-gateway, joomla3.0, virtuemart

I have my website with virtuemart 3 and joomla 3.

Virtuemart configuration One Page Checkout enabled and Ajax for OPC is selected.
there are 2 payment methods bank transfer and paypal.

My issue is initially whenever I go to checkout page and I select payment radio button, payment method is updated...If again I update payment method its not updated.

in short, only once payment method is updated. even If I hit save button its not updated.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPNfV.png)

anyone suggest me?

Thanks

Comment: Have you contacted virtuemart? Have you customized the virtuemart code at all? You might get better support at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: There is not any customization...
But there is a template override and that was the issue....
Thank you for the hints......